# int16_t becomes int32_t F filled

Tags: c

I can't understand why this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


typedef int16_t my_type;

my_type value = 0xFC7F;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  printf("0x%02X\n", value);
  printf("Type uses %lu bytes\n", sizeof(my_type));
}
```

outputs this

```
0xFFFFFC7F
Type uses 2 bytes
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

instead of

```
0xFC7F
Type uses 2 bytes
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I am using XCode 5 on OSX 10.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing with printf format specifier X, which is for integers.

Use the [`h` length specifier](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) to show it as a short.

[Live demo](http://codepad.org/Mztyn96L)

Comment: `X` is for *unsigned* integers.

Comment: Very true.  The OP should have used `uint16_t`, but `printf` doesn't complain.  The promotions and coercions all conspire to give what the OP probably _wants_ even though technically the mixing of signed and unsigned is very error prone.

Comment: @RayToal: I believe `int` and `unsigned int` are *layout-compatible*, so it's actually fine (even by 3.10/10), just implementation-defined.

Comment: Indeed, you can't use `%X` with signed types that have negative values, regardless of whether you use the `h` flag or not. If OP wants the result modulo 65536, this modulo operation needs to be done explicitly before passing the value to `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

With each of the `[u]int_t` types come macros for `printf` formats.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

printf("%" PRId16 "\n", value);
```

will print you the value correctly.

The `d` in the macro name should be used since this is a signed type, the `16` goes for the width of the type. Using `h` format modifiers might not always be correct, e.g on a machine where `int16_t` is the same as `int` and not `short`.

*Edit:* If you really want to see your `value` as hex you should first of all use a different type. Integer tokens in C always have a positive value, so in your example `0xFC7F` is bigger than `0x7FFF` and does definitively not fit into an `int16_t`. The "first fit" rule for hex constants implies that it has a type that is either unsigned or has more than 16 bit. Your initialization converts this positive value in an implementation defined manner to a signed value. Don't do that, this might not be portable.

If you are interested in integers just for their bit pattern (and a hex printout is basically that) use unsigned types

```
uint16_t value = 0xFC7F;
```

and print it with

```
printf("%" PRIX16 "\n", value);
```

or with

```
printf("%#" PRIX16 "\n", value);
```

if you want to have it with a `0x` prefix.

Comment: Where PRId16 is defined?

Comment: @kilianc, sorry I should have mentioned this, please see my edit.

Comment: Should be `printf("0x%02" PRIX16 "\n", (uint16_t) value);`

Comment: @kilianc, perhaps you should try to listen, bashing on people that try to give you a correct answer is what makes *me* sad. No it doesn't fit a 2 byte signed integer, `INT16_MAX` is `0x7FFF`. Your initialization converts that positive value in an implementation defined way into an `int16_t`.

Comment: @JensGustedt apologize for my rant. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @JensGustedt here is question for you: how do you write -1 in a int16_t since is 0xffff

Comment: @kilianc, what is wrong with `-1` or if you insist, `-0x1`? And it *is* not `0xFFFF`, on your machine that value is represent with a bit pattern that corresponds to the value `0xFFFFU`, these are two different things, value and representation. As I said if you are interested in bit patterns, use unsigned types, there is no ambiguity how to handle a sign bit.

Comment: @JensGustedt I think the misunderstanding here is that when I say 0xffff I refer to the raw value in ram and not the decimal value. 0xffff is -1 in a 2 bytes signed integer.

Comment: @kilianc, when you give it as an initializer, it is the value that is taken and not the bit pattern. And `0xFFFF` is only the bit pattern for `-1` if the sign representation is two's complement. Since there are three different sign representations that are allowed for C, it is always difficult to argue what bit pattern corresponds to a negative value. All of this is much easier for `unsigned` types where the bit pattern is prescribed exactly by the standard.

Comment: @JensGustedt I agree, that's why I started reading and writing a file as input for my tests.